# Remove Word using Preg_Replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, echo

I have the following php which pulling back text:

```
if( $this->sitemap->params->get('show_menutitle') )
echo '<h2 class="menutitle">'.$menu->name.'</h2>';
```

Each time it runs it pull's back:

```
About Menu
Support Menu
Contact Menu
```

I need to remove the text `Menu` from all instances, but can't figure out the preg_replace to add to the above.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Which *menu* would you like to remove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a regex to replace a constant.

```
echo '<h2 class="menutitle">'.str_replace(" Menu","",$menu->name).'</h2>';
```